# Input string was not in a correct format using c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried many solutions but i can't figure out what i am doing wrong?

I find this solution from everywhere but it's not working

```
 try
 {
 if (lbl_Unit.Text == "0")
 {
   lbl_Profit.Text = "0";
 }
 else
 {
   double a = double.Parse(lbl_TotalSold.Text);
   double b = double.Parse(lbl_Unit.Text);
   double total = a - b;
   lbl_Profit.Text = total.ToString();
 }
}
catch (Exception se)
{
   MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
}
```

This was my old code

```
try
 {
 if (lbl_Unit.Text == "0")
 {
   lbl_Profit.Text = "0";
 }
 else
 {
   int a = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_TotalSold.Text);
   int b = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_Unit.Text);
   int total = a - b;
   lbl_Profit.Text = total.ToString();
 }
}
catch (Exception se)
{
   MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
}
```

Comment: Use `double.TryParse(...)`

Comment: Just as the error states, the string you're trying to convert is not valid for what you're trying to convert it to.  What is the string value you're trying to convert?  Hint: It's not a double.

Comment: Check your input string for both that `Label`. You cannot leave it blank as it cannot parse empty string

Comment: @john i used TryParse but i am getting error on TryParse `double a = double.TryParse(lbl_TotalSold.Text);`

Comment: @David I don't have string value on my labels i am trying to convert int value.

Comment: @Usama See the question yours is a duplicate of. It shows an example.

Comment: @Usama Also, note that "" (a blank string) is still a non-numeric value. It is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TryParse unless Parse
For validate the number format. I recommend to review the decimal separator too

Comment: Any Code example?